# How to display the distro name (only) from lsb_release -i

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to retrieve the distro name from the `lsb_release -i` output, but using

```
lsb_release -i | sed 's/Distributor ID: //g'
```

won't do the trick.

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe should I change the tool?

Comment: I don't know `lsb_release` and it's not installed on my system. Can you please show us the output of the command before you pipe it into `sed`?

Answer (score 8):

You do not have to manipulate the output if you add the `-s` or `--short` option which according to the help "show requested information in short format".

```
lsb_release -is
```

Answer (score 2):

The character after the colon is a tab, not a space. Use

```
s/Distributor ID:\t//
```

The `/g` is not needed because the pattern is not repeated on the line.

You can also use much simpler

```
lsb_release -i | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lsb_release -is
```

Per the `man` page of `lsb_release(1)`:

```
   -s, --short
          Use the short output format for any information displayed.  This format omits the leading header(s).
```

On my machine:

```
bburns@bjb-laptop:~$ lsb_release -is
Ubuntu
```